# Sql Server INNER JOIN with 3 tables

Tags: sql, inner-join

I need the sum of totalfinal where nfc_data = '20210401' and nfc_codigosituacao = 00 and pro_departamento = 'ff'

I'm learning sql, and I was really confused by this inner join, I appreciate the help.

```
select
  a.nfc_totalfinal,
  a.nfc_data,
  a.nfc_registroproduto,
  b.nfc_codigosituacao,
  p.pro_registro,
  p.pro_departamento
from tblNFCeBody a, tblNFCeHeader b, tblProdutos p
```

Comment: When asking SQL questions add appropriate tags for the SINGLE database platform you are using and provide sample data for all tables and expected results in text form.

Comment: There is no inner join there. It's a cross join. There are no join conditions

Comment: If you're asking "how do I do the inner join to satisfy my requirements", we can't answer that. You need to understand what the join fields are between the three tables.

Answer (score 0):

Without any sample data, it is impossible to know which columns should be keys for JOIN criteria. You need to specify which columns will join off one another. Here is what the schema could look like.

```
SELECT  a.nfc_totalfinal
        ,a.nfc_data
        ,a.nfc_registroproduto
        ,b.nfc_codigosituacao
        ,p.pro_registro
        ,p.pro_departamento
FROM    tblNFCeBody AS a
        INNER JOIN tblNFCeHeader AS b ON a.TableAKeyColumn = b.TableAKeyColumn
        INNER JOIN tblProdutos AS p ON p.TableBKeyColumn = p.TableBKeyColumn;
```